# Nicer FTP client than FileZilla?

Tags: software-recommendation, ftp

FileZilla is really kind of "meh," when it comes to user interface. I'm wondering if there's something simpler/cleaner/slicker out there?

Comment: you may use some kind of browser plugin like [fireftp](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) for firefox

Comment: I second you, still no good FTP client for ubuntu. I use SmartFTP on windows and am trying to switch to Ubuntu but having hard time finding comparable software.

Comment: @Ejaz: As some people have asked elsewhere, it's more useful if you tell what is missing that you really need or what really bothers you.

Comment: @JanC thanks for asking for suggestions. I would love to see these three missing features implemented. **1.** Download/Upload buttons for selected files **2.** Drag'n drop to file explorer **3.** Address/location bar that spans width of local/remote window in "Widescreen" layout.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

FileZilla is the de-facto standard when it comes to an FTP client. It is extremely powerful while remaining very easy to use. You mentioned the user interface, and you're really not going to find much better then FileZilla as far as that. However, here are the top ten most popular alternatives:

### 1. Nautilus

Don't forget the FTP client that comes with Ubuntu! It integrates very nicely with Ubuntu, and is very easy to use. You don't have to install any additional software. However, it lacks many of the powerful features that a full-featured FTP client, like FileZilla has.

To use it, go to `File` > `Connect to Server` with the desktop selected.

[image]

### 2. gFTP

Another option is to use gFTP, a FTP client with a nice graphical interface that is different from FileZilla's, but only slightly. It can be installed through the Ubuntu Software Center or through `sudo apt-get install gftp`.

[image]

### 3. Kasablanca

Kasablanca is a GUI FTP client intended for use in KDE, but it will work in Unity too. The interface is very simple and it lacks some of the advanced features of more sophisticated FTP clients. It can be downloaded [here](http://download.berlios.de/kasablanca/kasablanca_0.3.1-1_i386.deb).

[image]

### 4. FireFTP

If you prefer a Firefox add-on, FireFTP is a great one that will allow you to transfer files from within the browser. Download it [here](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/).

[image]

### 5. KFTPgrabber

A FTP client for the K Desktop Environment (KDE). It can be downloaded at [kftp.org](http://kftp.org).

[image]

### 6. GNOME Commander

GNOME Commander is an FTP client with a very unique interface that supports themes and customization. It can be installed through the Ubuntu Software Center or `sudo apt-get install gnome-commander`.

[image]

### 7. Sitecopy

Sitecopy is a unique FTP client in that it automatically synches a directory on your computer with a directory on an FTP site automatically in the background. Details at the project's website, which can be found [here](http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/). Sorry, but I couldn't find a screenshot for this one.

### 8. Filerunner

Filerunner is an FTP client with a very basic interface. It can be installed through the Ubuntu Software Center or through `sudo apt-get install filerunner`.

[image]

### 9. Konqueror

Konqueror, a web browser for KDE, can access FTP sites when you type `ftp://username@server.com/` into the address bar. it can be installed through the Ubuntu Software Center or through `sudo apt-get install konqueror`.

[image]

### 10. net2ftp

net2ftp is an online FTP client which lets you upload files from the web browser without having to install any additional software. It can be accessed through net2ftp.com.

[image]

Hope that helped. Please let me know if I left any clients out that you think should be included.

Comment: Although I'm not sure any of these are better then FileZilla.

Comment: Agreed. But they should be considered.

Comment: Filezilla is a solid client why would one need a 'better' one? I have not tested all but some and i think filezilla is fine and all sorts of hosts and web guys recommend it all the time!

Comment: Well thought out answer, plus I completely agree about Nautilus.

Comment: In Nautilus you can also press Ctrl+L and then type or paste an ftp/ftps/sftp/scp URL, then press enter.

Comment: Stupid me!!! (linux noob): "Connect to Server" .....  Please, can someone slap me in my stupid face? thank you for that answer!

Comment: This does not answer the question, or may be it does but it is has a lot of unnecessary content. Since the question was "**Nicer** FTP client than FileZilla?", the first paragraph can be considered a complete answer where it says something along the lines of "There is none, that's the best you're going to get". Rest of the answer is just fluff that can be found on any of millions of "Best FTP client for linux" blog posts on the web.

Comment: @William sorry for my tone if it sounds rude. I'm just frustrated by the silly issues in such a good FTP client, and not to mention that it is free. I just want to  see Filezilla implement these features.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about that Nautilus feature! It was the most convenient for me. I connected by entering `ftp://DOMAIN-HERE.com` and then choosing to connect as a user.

Answer (score 4):

gftp - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gFTP

[image: gftp]

What features do you want that FileZilla, fireftp, or gftp lack ?

Comment: It's just the layout itself. FileZilla feels cluttered to me. There's no reason to have panes for local folder listing, remote folder listing, and then BELOW those panes, local files within the folder and remote files. It's too much. A complete interface redesign would be cool.

Comment: This is really good. Copying I cant do from filezilla but this one did the trick

Comment: Are you able to bypass loading from ~/.ssh? I hate FZ so much because even though I specify that I only want to use password and not SSH keys, it still tries all the keys and ends up causing an error (too many authentication failures)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable panels from View menu and leave only local and remote views without local and remote files parts below, ftp commands above and queue window on the bottom. You can change toolbars. There are nice styles installed by default. You can even change whole interface layout in Edit->Settings->Interface window. Filezilla is the best for me but it was not easy to start with it. Now I feel the power :)

[image: Two panels only]

Comment: is there a way to make the _address bars_ work like breadcrumbs? like in _explorer_ (or application corresponding to Windows explorer) in ubuntu? I.e., we can type in address manually and also use same address bar like breadcrumbs to jump between folders?

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a nice web-based FTP client, [www.monstaftp.com](http://www.monstaftp.com) is an open source PHP FTP file manager.