# ftp client other than filezilla for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ftp, upload

I am using filezilla from one year but i fed-up to using filezilla for it slow working. So i change it.
Please suggest me other ftp client for fast uploading in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: this has been asked before and is answered very well.

http://askubuntu.com/a/109020/158420

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, then try FireFTP.  FireFTP is a free, secure, cross-platform FTP client for Mozilla Firefox which provides easy and intuitive access to FTP servers.  You can download [here](http://fireftp.net/).

Another one is FileRunner.  FileRunner is an X-Based FTP program. It gives you a windowed view of files on your local system and a remote system. It allows transferring multiple files at once, tagging of files, etc.

To install Filerunner, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install filerunner
```

<sup>Source:Ubuntugeek</sup>