# Filezilla File Download Problem

Tags: 14.04, filezilla

I'm using filezilla on Ubuntu 14.04. But I didn't get any way to download file by FilleZilla. Drag and Drop like windows is not working and not even direct download option.

Please help.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Nicer FTP client than FileZilla?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109000/nicer-ftp-client-than-filezilla). It will help you to troubleshoot whether you have a problem with the Filezilla interface or maybe you have a networking issue. That's one good thing about the Ubuntu Software Center - there are alternative applications available so it helps you to troubleshoot the issue when things go wrong with an application.

Comment: Hi Karel, Thanks. But is there any way to download file by filezilla with drag and drop like windows Filezilla does?

Comment: @SisyphusExcerpt -  there is [gFTP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gftp/) (cant test whether it supports drag + drop though(

Comment: I use FileZilla on lubuntu 12.04 and it works fine, like FileZilla on Windows. May be there are same problem, did you get errors during installation process? Did you check `/var/log/syslog`? Could you post FileZilla log during Drag and Drop?

Comment: Thanks @Letizia, I'm new with Ubuntu. I didn’t get any error with installation. I installed it from Ubuntu Software Centre. Not only drap and drop. Download from Filezilla is not working at all. I can see you answered my another question ( Same Problem actually ). Please let me know what I supposed to get from  /var/log/syslog

Comment: Is a text file where system logs activity information and report errors. You can read from file manager or opening terminal and exec `less /var/log/syslog` command. If you post it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) I'll verify for you if there are some errors

Comment: @Letizia http://pastebin.com/4u9t3yW5. I'll be greatefull if you can help. Please.....

Comment: @Letizia, When I drag it to any folder ( That is already have write permission ) not working. And when I right click on any server file from Filezilla, I'm getting this:

Error: Failed to open "/index.php" for writing
Error: File transfer failed

Thanks

Comment: Could you check if disk is full with `df -k` command? and `df -i` command? I'm sorry, but I don't found useful information in syslog.

Comment: Yeah. I checked but its fine. Think, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did the error exactly "Error: Failed to open "/index.php" ? It seems that FileZilla is trying to write `/` folder. If so then the error is true, `/` folder is writable only by root.

Comment: Yes, Exactly that. But How can I change download location of Filezilla and why drag and drop is now working.. ?? :( :(

Comment: In the left side there is "local site" bar, type `/home/yourUser` and try to upload one file from server for test

Comment: Hey, its working now. When I double click on a file from server or drag and drop, its taking path from Left side of Filezilla, and it was root. Now when I changed it to public, everything is working. Thanks a ton.... :) :) :)