# Filezilla crashes ubuntu 16.04 lts- Please suggest alternate

Tags: 16.04, ftp, filezilla

Suddenly filezilla has started behaving abnormally..
As and when i try to connect to some ftp from the  site manager , filezilla crashes and automatically closes..

If I try to connect via quick connect then it connects to the ftp but doesn't show any file or directory..

I am really struck here . my speed of working has been halved . I tried using gftp but its not as convenient as filezilla.

Please help me out with filezilla or suggest me an equivalent ftp client

Comment: Maybe this can help:
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/109000/nicer-ftp-client-than-filezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109000/nicer-ftp-client-than-filezilla)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the basic `ssh` and `sftp` because I learned how to use them long ago, and I find them easy to use.

But you may find it easier to use the standard file browser 'Files' alias `nautilus` in standard Ubuntu. Click on the symbol with three horizontal lines and select 'Enter Location', and type the IP address. In a local network you can type

```
sftp://192.168.0.2
```

if that is the address to your server. If you open another window with 'Files' you can copy between the windows (if you have write access).

You can create a bookmark if you intend to connect to this address again.  Click on the symbol with three horizontal lines and select 'Bookmark this location'.

---

In case you are using a custom port e.g. `1234` and want to connect directly to a specific remote directory e.g. `/var/www/example.com` with the username `someUser` then type:

```
sftp://someUser@192.168.0.2:1234/var/www/example.com
```

---

If you have problems also with 'Files', I think there is some other problem, maybe with the network or with some tool under the hood, and not with Filezilla.

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply ....  I will try nautilus  ...  I don't think that is the case because I am able to see the files & directories in filezilla  .. I will try & learn ssh & sftp once I get through my current work

Comment: You are welcome. Please let us know, if and how your problem is solved :-)

Comment: hey nautilus is just great..  It is just  like just moving files from one drive to other .. Because the solution was regarding the alternate ftp client so I will edit the question title a bit .. I hope you don't mind  ..Thanks once again....  +1

Comment: this is a horrible alternative for remote connections (bet works great on your LAN) constantly drops

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is a late reply though I faced the similar issue with FileZilla. Following steps resolved it for me.

1. In the site manager, choose your site and on the right hand side, choose logon type as key file
2. Give path of your .pem file. (You need to choose all files to see .pem file)
3. You would get a prompt. choose to continue/ok.

And you are good to go. It will not crash any further and will connect to your server.

Note: In the edit -> settings -> SFTP, I have added my .pem file as well. Not sure if it is required now after using above two steps but it is there.

Regards,