# How do you send and receive data from one machine to another?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, remote, remote-access, raspberrypi

Good day, AskUbuntu! As the title implies, I would like to know if it's possible to subscribe and receive data from a terminal running from another Ubuntu desktop, and how one would go about doing so.

I tried to look around for the answer prior, but I only seem to find remote desktop queries, which I don't believe is what I'm looking for. I don't mean to control a desktop using another or transfer files, but rather, use the published data from one's terminal to another.

If it's worth mentioning, my application is to have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu MATE transmit sensory data (specifically my Kinect v2) to my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 for processing (specifically using the Kinect's input to create a 3D map). Unfortunately, the RPi3 lacks the processing power to compile my programs (using ROS, but that's a different story) as well as generate a 3D map, so I need a separate and more powerful machine to do so. The reason why I can't just use my laptop directly is because I am using it on a mobile platform with wheels, and can't fully support the weight of it.

TL;DR - Is there a way to subscribe to a node from another machine and process its data in another?

Thank you, and good day.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use **netcat** to both send and receive TCP packets:

### Server

```
echo "hello" | netcat [client-ip-address] [port]
```

### Client

```
netcat [server-ip-address] [port]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would install [openssh-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html) in the Raspberry Pi 3 (in Ubuntu MATE).

You can use `ssh`, `sftp`, `rsync` and several other tools to access the data from another computer via ssh, when you run `openssh-server` in the Raspberry Pi 3. I am happy with command line tools, but it is also possible to use tools with a graphical user interface.

See these links for more details,

[help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html)

[askubuntu.com/questions/897301/filezilla-crashes-ubuntu-16-04-lts-please-suggest-alternate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897301/filezilla-crashes-ubuntu-16-04-lts-please-suggest-alternate/897305#897305)

[askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398)